# How to serve (properly) a react-router with go?

Tags: go, react-router

Im trying to serve a react-router with go, i already did it, but i'm having troubles, i think the way i did is not the correct one, or it's not complete. Im using Mux. The trouble im having is that when i push the `<Link>`'s in my app it changes de view correctly, but when i try to change it directly from the browser or i try to reload the page i get a 404 error

I've tried diferent ways, im actually doing this way:

```
func main() {

    var dir = "./static"

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(fs)


    fmt.Println("Server running in port :8000")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))

}
```

I want the server to serve the same directory in all request like "/", "/example", "/example2", etc.

Comment: Check this article: https://medium.com/@kimrgrey/integration-of-create-react-app-into-golang-server-47074b8dcd7d

Comment: I ckecked it, thank you Cyro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have some static content and you'd like everything else to forward to the `index.html`.  I had a similar problem, and my solution was to just prefix all the react-router urls with a constant so I could detect that on the backend and forward it.  My code looks something like this:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
router.HandleFunc("/", handleIndex).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/h/{param:.*}", handleIndex).Methods("GET")
```

And in my react-router I just changed all the routes from `{uri}` to `/h/{uri}`

If you really want to forward everything to the react code without any backend checking for 404s or anything, you could do:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.NotFoundHandler = ... // Write a function to serve the index file here
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))
router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(fs)
```

Comment: I just realized that what i asked has not too much sense, your options really help me, thank you